# Is there a problem with this MySQL Query?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, object

```
public function create() {


        echo $this->equipment->getCatId() . "<br/>";
        echo $this->equipment->getName() . "<br/>";
        echo $this->equipment->getYear() . "<br/>";
        echo $this->equipment->getManufacturer() . "<br/>";
        echo $this->equipment->getModel() . "<br/>";
        echo $this->equipment->getPrice() . "<br/>";
        echo $this->equipment->getLocation() . "<br/>";
        echo $this->equipment->getCondition() . "<br/>";
        echo $this->equipment->getStockNum() . "<br/>";
        echo $this->equipment->getInformation() . "<br/>";
        echo $this->equipment->getDescription() . "<br/><br/>";


        $db = Connect::connect();
        $current_time = date('y M d');
        $query = "INSERT INTO equipment (cat_id, name, year, manufacturer, model, price, location, condition,
                                         stock_num, information, description, created, modified)

                                         VALUES

                                        ({$this->equipment->getCatId()}, {$this->equipment->getName()}, {$this->equipment->getYear()},
                                         {$this->equipment->getManufacturer()}, {$this->equipment->getModel()}, {$this->equipment->getPrice()},
                                         {$this->equipment->getLocation()}, {$this->equipment->getCondition()}, {$this->equipment->getStockNum()},
                                         {$this->equipment->getInformation()}, {$this->equipment->getDescription()}, '$current_time', '$current_time')";

        $result = $db->query($query);

        return $db->insert_id;

    }
```

- The echos at the top all display valid data that fit the database schema.
- There are no connection errors

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the echo'ed query

INSERT INTO equipment (cat_id, name, year, manufacturer, model, price, location, condition, stock_num, information, description, created, modified) VALUES (1, 'r', 1, 'sdf', 'sdf', '2', 'd', 'd', '3', 'asdfasdfdf', 'df', '10 May 10', '10 May 10')

MySQL is giving: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition, stock_num, information, description, created, modified) VALUES (1, 'r' at line 1

id      int(11) unsigned    NO  PRI     NULL    auto_increment
    Edit    Delete  cat_id  int(11) unsigned    NO      NULL
    Edit    Delete  prod_name   varchar(255)    YES         NULL
    Edit    Delete  prod_year   varchar(10)     YES         NULL
    Edit    Delete  manufacturer    varchar(255)    YES         NULL
    Edit    Delete  model   varchar(255)    YES         NULL
    Edit    Delete  price   varchar(10)     YES         NULL
    Edit    Delete  location    varchar(255)    YES         NULL
    Edit    Delete  condition   varchar(25)     YES         NULL
    Edit    Delete  stock_num   varchar(128)    YES         NULL
    Edit    Delete  information     text    YES         NULL
    Edit    Delete  description     text    YES         NULL
    Edit    Delete  created     varchar(20)     YES         NULL
    Edit    Delete  modified    varchar(20)     YES         NULL

Query: INSERT INTO equipment (cat_id, prod_name, prod_year, manufacturer, model, price, location, condition, stock_num, information, description, created, modified) VALUES (1, 'asdf', '234', 'adf', 'asdf', '34', 'asdf', 'asdf', '234', 'asdf', 'asdf', '10 May 10', '10 May 10')

Here is the SQL export from PhpMyAdmin in case someone wants to try duplicating this issue: http://pastie.org/954206

BLEHBLEHSDFOHSE  --  So apparently, 'condition' is also a reserved word... threw in some backticks, then it started working.

Comment: didn't knew about that one too.. nice catch. :-)

Comment: Syntax errors happen way before MySQL would touch the database, so they cannot be related with anything not present in that single query (such as column types). The error message for syntax errors is ridiculously unhelpful (though the quoted string does start at the exact point of error); using something that can syntax highlight (such as the MySQL Query Browser) helps to avoid a lot of basic errors without wasting much time.

Comment: That SQL/PHP mix is hideous, you need to use MySQL binding statements instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YEAR is a reserved word in MySQL. If you're going to use it, you're going to need to backtick (i.e. `` `year` ``)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming location, information and description are strings quotes are missing.

```
INSERT INTO equipment (cat_id, name, year, manufacturer, model, price, location, condition,
                                         stock_num, information, description, created, modified)

                                         VALUES

                                        ({$this->equipment->getCatId()}, {$this->equipment->getName()}, {$this->equipment->getYear()},
                                         '{$this->equipment->getManufacturer()}', {$this->equipment->getModel()}, {$this->equipment->getPrice()},
                                         '{$this->equipment->getLocation()}', {$this->equipment->getCondition()}, {$this->equipment->getStockNum()},
                                         '{$this->equipment->getInformation()}', '{$this->equipment->getDescription()}', '$current_time', '$current_time')";
```

Comment: how would you go about applying quotes to a method that returns a string?

And by string, do you mean text?

Comment: By doing '{$this->equipment->getLocation()}' as in the example.

Comment: @ThinkinBits   '{$this->equipment->getInformation()}' like this.

Comment: I added quotes to all the varchar/text fields, and left ints as is; still with no luck

Comment: What is the result of echo $query?

Also, do a query for 'describe equipment' and paste the results of echoing the output of that please.

Answer (score 0):

Varchar, char and text fields need quotes around them to insert.  Echo out the SQL query and check this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i see it at this point, your problem was year field with no quotes...

> INSERT INTO equipment (cat_id, name,
>   year, manufacturer, model, price,
>   location, condition, stock_num,
>   information, description, created,
>   modified) VALUES (1, 'r', **1**, 'sdf',
>   'sdf', '2', 'd', 'd', '3',
>   'asdfasdfdf', 'df', '10 May 10', '10
>   May 10')

here, the problem is cat_id WITH quotes

> Query: INSERT INTO equipment (cat_id,
>   name, year, manufacturer, model,
>   price, location, condition, stock_num,
>   information, description, created,
>   modified) VALUES (**'1'**, 'asdf', '234',
>   'adf', 'asdf', '34', 'asdf', 'asdf',
>   '234', 'asdf', 'asdf', '10 May 10',
>   '10 May 10')

Comment: INSERT INTO equipment (cat_id, name, prod_year, manufacturer, model, price, location, condition, stock_num, information, description, created, modified) VALUES (1, 'asdf', '234', 'adf', 'asdf', '34', 'asdf', 'asdf', '234', 'asdf', 'asdf', '10 May 10', '10 May 10') still produces a syntax error

Comment: @ThinkingInBits: there was no prod_year in your definition.

Comment: - did you change the year field to prod_year at the table too? is that field still varchar??
--- 
is the table name correctly spelled?
--- 
have you tried that query at the command line?
--- getting out of ideas! :-)

Comment: I changed year and name to prod_year and prod_name just to see if there was some kind of naming conflict.  I'm typing this SQL directly into phpMyAdmin and I'm getting syntax errors.

Comment: can you select any data from that table?

is there any possibility you're executing the statement at the wrong database?

Comment: if you do "SELECT * FROM equipment" ??? Does it return an error, any row or an empty set?

Answer (score 0):

BLEHBLEHSDFOHSE -- So apparently, 'condition' is also a reserved word... threw in some backticks, then it started working.

Comment: If it's working, please come back and mark one of these answers as "the" answer so we can move on and stop trying to answer the question ...

Answer (score 0):

Stop using mysql_query() and switch to mysqli and [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php), then you don't need all that obtuse OOP in your SQL string.  It would look cleaner like this:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO table (id,name,age) VALUES (?,?,?)';
```